# Combine two observables, act on one of them

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an input field providing an `Observable<String>` (emitting whenever a change to the input text is made) and a button providing an `Observable<Click>` (emitting every click).

When a `click` is received, I want to use the latest `String` emission to update another text field.

What's the best way to combine these two Observables? `combineLatest` won't work because I would receive an `onNext` every time the input text changes.

Comment: Rather than try to observe the text field, I would just pass the text field itself to the button observer.  Then on click take the current value of its text and use that.

Comment: @markspace I just thought about that too, yet searched for an answer for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[WithLatestFrom](http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom) does what I wanted.

Usage:

```
    view.sendButtonClick().withLatestFrom(view.inputText(), BiFunction<Click, String, String> { click, text ->
        text
    }).subscribe {

        Log.d("xyz", it) // Logs the inputText string

    }
```

Comment: Hum... When you receive a click you will act on the latest 2 text changes. Not just the latests. Thats what that diagram shows. I would say that is not what you described.

Comment: @pedromss No, I will receive onNext when a click was emitted, delivering the latest text input.